# How do I pass text into a javascript variable/function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create inline "tweetable quotes".  For example:

1) User clicks on a line of text, noted with a highlight/different color to indicate that it's clickable. E.g.

```
<span class="tweetable_quote">this is an amazing quote</span>
```

2) Window opens using Twitter intent[1] with the quote included. E.g.

```
window.open("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=this%20is%20an%20amazing%20quote")
```

How can I pass in the text ("this is an amazing quote") as a URL encoded variable to be used within the Twitter intent URL?  Note that there may be several "tweetable quotes" on the same page.

Thanks in advance for the help!

[1] https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents

**UPDATE**

I tried implementing the suggestion below, adding the following code in the :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//  this will be the click handler for all elements with the "tweetable_quote" class.
$(".tweetable_quote").on('click',function(){
  // $(this) refers to the element that was clicked.
  var text = $(this).text();
  window.open("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text="+encodeURIComponent(text));
});
</script>

<span class="tweetable_quote">This is some quotable text.</span>
```

When the page loads, the following error is displayed in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on'
(anonymous function)
```

Comment: My apologies and thanks for the trip, Lix! I will go back and make sure to appreciate those who've helped me in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    var $quoteEl = $('.tweetable_quote');

    $quoteEl.on('click',function(){
      var text = $(this).text();
      window.open("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text="+encodeURIComponent(text));
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: basically needs to wrap it inside the document ready function

Comment: Thanks! Works beautifully :)

Answer (score 1):

Could be done something like this, using [jQuery](http://jquery.com).

```
$('.tweetable_quote').on('click', function() {
  window.open("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" + encodeURIComponent ($(this).text()));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for -

```
//  this will be the click handler for all elements with the "tweetable_quote" class.
$(".tweetable_quote").on('click',function(){
  // $(this) refers to the element that was clicked.
  var text = $(this).text();
  window.open("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text="+encodeURIComponent(text));
});
```

I'm using the [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) function here to correctly encode the text -

> **encodeURIComponent** - Encodes a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) component by replacing
>   each instance of certain characters by one, two, three, or four escape
>   sequences representing the UTF-8 encoding of the character (will only
>   be four escape sequences for characters composed of two "surrogate"
>   characters).

Comment: Thanks, @Lix but I receive the following console error when the page loads:

**Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on' testing: (anonymous function)**

Code:

<script type="text/javascript">
"tweetable_quote" class.
$(".tweetable_quote").on('click',function(){
  var text = $(this).text();
  window.open("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text="+encodeURIComponent(text));
});
</script>

<span class="tweetable_quote">This is a quotable sentence.</span>